# Cannot copy csv file inside a cassandra table

Tags: csv, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I create a standard csv file using COPY/TO and now I want to upload the content using COPY/FROM inside of another cassandra table. However, I get the following error:

```
Failed to import 5000 rows: Error - field larger than field limit (131072),  given up after 1 attempts
Exceeded maximum number of insert errors 1000
Failed to process 5000 rows; failed rows written to import_point_labeled_results.err
Exceeded maximum number of insert errors 1000
Processed: 0 rows; Rate:       0 rows/s; Avg. rate:       0 rows/s
0 rows imported from 0 files in 6.639 seconds (0 skipped).
```

The csv has some 900k entries. And yes, some column content is larger than 131072 but that is unavoidable and cannot be changed. How do I fix this issue / bypass this problem? I would really like to do so without having to reboot the whole cluster.

Edit:

I tried to follow the advice of changing `./cqlshrc` and increase the field_size_limit however when I increase it to `10000000000000000000` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 2421, in <module>
   main(*read_options(sys.argv[1:], os.environ))
 File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 2329, in main
   csv.field_size_limit(options.field_size_limit)
TypeError: limit must be an integer
```

Even if I decrease the value minimally it will still not be enough to upload everything in my csv and any higher it throws this error.
Any alternatives?

Edit 2;

The csv file has no more than 10 columns but one column contains results from analysis and it can contain a lot of data. A line from the csv would be:

```
peinfo,sample,287da2f0-61f0-11e7-89ae-000c2936efb4,NotSend,,2017-07-06 02:09:35.745+0000,{'NotSend'},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,1,NotSend,81dbe6ba82bb0311aa0b311bae06781302345cd6e07d5bdd3d7eae08a37bb8a0,{'NotSend'},{'NotSend'},,NotSend,['NotImplemented'],NotImplemented,NotImplemented
```

Comment: How many columns do you have ? Can you show sample of your csv file ?

Comment: I added those details in my post under Edit 2

Comment: I think the problem is in your csv format. Some column may contains text with unescaped comma. That's why cqlsh thinks it is another column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the `cqlshrc.sample` file (location depends on your installation, you can see it in [github](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/73fa27cc6ae35a16ab8b828f9872ce59063aa83d/conf/cqlshrc.sample) otherwise), you will find that you can increase this limit.

```
[csv]
;; The size limit for parsed fields
; field_size_limit = 131072
```

So you should edit your .cqlshrc (usually in ~/.cassandra/cqlshrc, you might need to create it) to configure this limit.

Comment: Nop. It's purely a client configuration that gets loaded when you start cqlsh. Just make sure to configure it on the machine you will start cqlsh and issue the COPY command.

Comment: can you please check my edit? this solution worked, as in it changed the limit, but the upload still doesn't work

Comment: What value did you use for the field_size_limit?

Comment: 10000000000000000000, any less than that and it still wont upload most rows of the csv

Comment: Can you try with 9223372036854775807? I think that's the max int according to `sys.maxint`

Comment: The error does not appear but it is still not big enough to accommodate my csv rows.

Comment: Can you try to edit your cqlsh.py file, and set the value directly there: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/6fc3699adb4f609f78a40888af9797bb205216b0/bin/cqlsh.py#L2351  This might work as it bypass the configs.getint() call line 2243

Comment: What value should I add? The upper-limit that I need to transfer the data? In that case, do you know any adverse effect inserting a very large number would have? (Like crashing the system) Also, it would still be bigger than an integer so the error should persist.

Comment: Try a larger value than  9223372036854775807. You could try 10000000000000000000 directly. Since you managed to extract your data via COPY TO, I expect you should be able to reinsert with COPY FROM, and that the limitation you are currently hitting is a bug in line 2243 of cqlsh.py. I didn't test, so I can't guarantee anything :)

Comment: If I put any number higher than 9223372036854775807, I hit the error message in my edit. Even if I alter cqlsh.py directly. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: Yea, makes sense. The limit you are hitting is related to the csv module which is used to parse your file. There is not much you can do about it, you can't go higher than 9223372036854775807.
I don't know your Cassandra data model, but I hope you are not using very large partitions (>100MB) or you will have issues in prod.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. The problem was (in my case) that I didn't had enough space left on my harddrive. 
The error message doesn't describe the real problem sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error but on Docker. The short answer is:

A file named `cqlshrc.sample` can be found inside `/etc/cassandra` in the official Cassandra Docker container. You'll find the block of code as shown below, which you will edit to match what's shown further below, rename the file to `cqlshrc` and move it to `/root/.cassandra/` and restart the cqlsh shell.

```
[csv]
;; The size limit for parsed fields
; field_size_limit = 131072
```

Set the limit to a higher number as shown and uncomment the line.

```
[csv]
;; The size limit for parsed fields
field_size_limit = 1000000000
```

The `cqlshrc` file has the configurations including credentials for the `cqlsh` tool. You can find more information [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh_commands/cqlshCqlshrc.html#Usingasamplecqlshrcfile).

**Steps for Cassandra Docker users:**

1. In the host machine, open up a folder and launch the terminal from it.
2. Get the container ID using the `docker ps` command.
3. Copy the file in the Docker container to the host machine to edit the contents as shown above using the command: `docker cp <CONTAINER ID>:/etc/cassandra/cqlshrc.sample .` (Don't forget the dot). Note that you can also use your terminal skills here instead.
4. Copy the edited and renamed file to the hidden `cassandra` directory in root using `docker cp cqlshrc <CONTAINER ID>:/root/.cassandra/`. If the target directory is not found in the container, create one by navigating to the root with `cd ~` and once there, `mkdir .cassandra`.
5. Get rid of the CQLSH shell you may be on currently and open up a new one and you should be all set!